# PHP Sort an array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array

```
$genreQuery = $con ->query ("select distinct(movie_year) from movies");

$movieGenre = array();
$movieTitle = array();
$movieList = array();

while($row = $genreQuery->fetch_object())  {
$movieGenre[] = $row;
}



foreach($movieGenre as $MGenre){
 $query = $con ->query 
 (" 
    select '$MGenre->movie_year' movie_year, IFNULL(count(*)/(select count(*) 
    from user_movie_ratings where user_id = '$userid'),0) rating
    from   user_movie_ratings umr,
    movies m
    where  umr.user_id = '$userid'
    and    umr.movie_id = m.id
    and    m.movie_year = '$MGenre->movie_year' ORDER BY rating DESC;
");

while($row = $query->fetch_object())  {
$movieTitle[] = $row;
}

}
$text = "";

foreach($movieTitle as $MTitle){

if (empty($text)){
    $text = "\"".$MTitle->movie_year."\"";}
else{
    $text = $text.",\"".$MTitle->movie_year."\"";
}
}

$list = $con ->query
(" 
    SELECT movie_name, avg_rating, image, id, genre
    FROM   movies       
    WHERE  id NOT IN (SELECT movie_id FROM user_movie_ratings WHERE user_id = '$userid')
    ORDER BY field(movie_year, $text), avg_rating DESC;
");

while($row = $list->fetch_object())  {
$movieList[] = $row;
}
```

The array is filled by the above query, what I want to do is sort it by the rating so that is looks like this

```
year       rating
2014       0.0001
2015       0.0000
2013       0.0000
1967       0.0000
....       ......
....       ......
etc        etc
```

I have tried adding `ORDER BY rating DESC` to the query, but that does not work and when I use `rsort($movieTitle)` it sorts by the year not the rating do I need to do some kind of multidimensional sort, or is there another way?

Comment: Why not apply an ORDER BY clause to your SQL query?

Comment: do you mean `ORDER BY rating DESC`, I tried that and it does not work (see above)

Comment: I made tables that I assume are functionally the same as yours and I simply added order by rating desc to the end of the query. The results were ordered by the rating from highest value to lowest value. In order to recreate your error, we need to know the exact column definitions you are using. Perhaps you are doing something very odd that is causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that ordering by `rating` does not work as you seem to be running multiple queries in a `foreach` loop and each iteration gets one year. So in that case, your order would be by year and then in the year by rating.

You should get rid of that loop and only do one query and then the condition and sort order would be:

```
...
AND m.movie_year IN (the,years,you,want)
ORDER BY rating DESC
```

By looping over the `$movieGenre` like you do now, you can easily generate a comma separated list for the years to use in the `IN` statement.

**Edit:** Based on your comment you want all years, so the `foreach` loop and the year condition in the query are unnecessary.

You probably want something like:

```
SELECT m.movie_year, IFNULL(count(*)/(select count(*) 
    from user_movie_ratings where user_id = '$userid'),0) rating
FROM user_movie_ratings umr,
    movies m
WHERE umr.user_id = '$userid'
    AND umr.movie_id = m.id
ORDER BY rating DESC
```

Assuming of course that the user ID is safe to use in a query, you should really use a prepared statement to avoid potential sql injection.

Now you have all your results in one query so there is no need for the outer loop any more.

Comment: the other query is `$genreQuery = $con ->query ("select distinct(movie_year) from movies");`

Comment: @McNoodles That doesn't make any sense, if you select all years any way, there is no need to add the year as a condition.

Comment: I have added the full code above, I need the distinct movie years so it only counts them once or am I wrong. Movie year is from a table of movies with info on them like year, genre and so on

Comment: @McNoodles Then you would need to `GROUP BY` the year for the count and  in the inner query where you calculate the score.

Comment: it only returns one year and its rating not all of them